# Potential leak of an object allocated on line ##

Tags: iphone, memory-management, xcode4.2

I am working on an iphone application, and although I thought I had a good understanding of memory management, I'm seeing some issues after using the Xcode Analyze function.  I have looked at many of the existing questions I could find on here, but I couldn't find one that was similar to my situation.

CustomerDetailController.h

```
@interface CustomerDetailController : UITableViewController {
  PTCustomer *customer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) PTCustomer *customer;

- (id)initWithCustomer:(PTCustomer *)aCustomer;
```

CustomerDetailController.m

```
@synthesize customer;

- (id)initWithCustomer:(PTCustomer *)aCustomer {
  if ((self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]))
  {
    if (aCustomer != nil)
      self.customer = aCustomer;
    else
      self.customer = [[PTCustomer alloc] init];  // This line shows Potential leak of an object allocated on line ##

  }
  return self;
}
```

If I click on the item marked by the Analyzer, it then says:

1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
2. Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

My reasoning behind this is that if a PTCustomer object was not passed in, I want to initialize a new one so that I have it available elsewhere within this class.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.customer` is being over-retained.
+1 for alloc of customer
+1 when the property setter retains customer.

Do not retain `customer`, the property setter will retain it.

Just:

```
self.customer = [[[PTCustomer alloc] init] autorelease];
```

But given that this is an init method there is a strong argument that the ivar should be assigned directly:

```
customer = [[PTCustomer alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to assign the retained object directly to `customer` rather than to `self.customer`.  This bypasses the auto-retain logic in the `setCustomer` method.  However, if you do that you must assure that any prior object referenced by `customer` is released  (eg, by assigning nil to `self.customer`).

(Because bypassing the setter in this way is a somewhat irregular technique some folks frown on it.)

Comment: Doesn't need to be an init method to set the value that way.

Comment: True but I always use ivars directly in init and dealloc methods, not necessary just that I have bought into that argument.

Answer (score 0):

Are you releasing your `customer` ivar in the dealloc? If not, there's your leak.

Comment: It is being over-retained. +1 for alloc of `customer`, +1 when the property setter retains `customer`.

Comment: Hm you're right about that. I missed the self. in the alloc line and thought he forgot the release in the dealloc. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes, I have `[customer release]` in the dealloc.